# Percentage is equal to zero

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me, I got stuck in this error "ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero" and another thing, when the value of column 1 (g.ticket) or column 2 (h.employee) is 0 I get 1 in ration instead 0. How to I solve that? Thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Query:

```
    select 'Data'
    ||','||to_char(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
    ||','||nvl(g.ticket, 0 )
    ||','||round((nvl(g.ticket,2) / nvl(h.employee,2)),2)
    ||','||nvl(h.employee,0)
    ||','||round((nvl(h.employee,2) / nvl(g.ticket,2)),2)
    from owner_dwh.dc_date d
    left join (
        select trunc(t.create_time,'IW') as ddate
              ,count(case when upper(ticket_customer_user_id) = upper('hcphuser') then 1   else null end) as ticket
        from app_account.otrs_ticket t 
        where t.create_time between to_date('02/20/2013','MM/dd/yyyy') and sysdate -1
        and queue_id in (4,6,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,20,27,28,30,31,32,35,36,37,38,39,40,44,45,46,47,50,52,53,55,56)
        group by trunc(t.create_time,'IW')
    ) g on d.dtime_day = g.ddate
    left join (
       select trunc(e.date_hired, 'IW') as hdate
             ,count(e.date_hired) as employee
       from app_account.hr_employee e
       where e.date_hired between to_date('02/20/2013','MM/dd/yyyy') and sysdate -1
       group by trunc(e.date_hired, 'IW')
   ) h on d.dtime_day = h.hdate
   where d.dtime_day between to_date('02/20/2013','MM/dd/yyyy') and trunc(sysdate) -1
   and trunc(d.dtime_day, 'IW')= d.dtime_day
   order by d.dtime_day;
```

Comment: This is a basic math question.  It's not valid to divide a number by 0.  If you try, you'll get an ORA-01476 error.  How you resolve that depends on what you want to happen in that case.  It makes little sense to divide by `nvl( <<some column>>, 0 )`.  If `<<some column>>` is NULL, you'll divide by 0 and get an error because you'll be dividing by 0.  What do you really want to happen if either of your denominators is `NULL`?

Comment: even i change 0 into 2 i get the same error

Comment: Can either `g.ticket` or `h.employee` have a value of 0?  That would also cause you to try to divide by 0.

Comment: i change both g.ticket and h.employee into 2, but that error always appear

Comment: @Yang: I don't think so. Division by two will never give you a "divisor is equal to zero" error. Care to post your updated query?

Comment: I already update my post. @ruakh

Comment: Thanks. So, what you said is wrong: you *didn't* "change both g.ticket and h.employee into 2"; you just changed the fall-back value to 2, when those are null. You're still trying to divide by zero when either g.ticket or h.employee is zero.

Comment: How can i change it properly? @ruakh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little but unclear what you really want to happen but you should be able to avoid getting ORA-01476 by using CASE expression. Please try something like this:

```
 select 'Data'
    ||','||to_char(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
    ||','||nvl(g.ticket, 0 )
    ||','||CASE WHEN nvl(h.employee,0) = 0 THEN 0 
                ELSE round((nvl(g.ticket,0) / h.employee),2) END
    ||','||nvl(h.employee,0)
    ||','||CASE WHEN nvl(g.ticket,0) = 0 THEN 0 
                ELSE round((nvl(h.employee,0) / g.ticket),2) END
    from owner_dwh.dc_date d
<REST OF STATEMENT>
```

Comment: There's an error ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: Sorry about that. The second CASE expression was invalid. Please try with the corrected statement?

Comment: I already solve the issue i just put 'nvl(' in divisor. thanks to you